# How to make modal overlay scrollable using CSS

Tags: css

How do I make my overlay scrollable when my modal's length has exceeded the current view's height?

My overlay currently has the following CSS:

```
.ngdialog-overlay {
  position: fixed;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-animation: ngdialog-fadein 0.5s;
  animation: ngdialog-fadein 0.5s;
}
```

If I remove the top, right, bottom and left properties, I can scroll outside the modal just fine, however I don't have any overlay visible.

Most of the solutions I've found in SO use the code above (with the exception of the -webkit and animation), but it's not working for me.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried overflow: auto; on the dialog?

```
.ngdialog-overlay {
  position: fixed;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-animation: ngdialog-fadein 0.5s;
  animation: ngdialog-fadein 0.5s;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: This should be a comment